# Is there any reason to keep the secret tag around?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, status-murdered

The [secret](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secret) tag doesn't seem to provide any useful information. Plus, once we discuss them in detail on the site, they don't exactly fit the description "secret" any more. It seems like another one of those meta tags that we've been murdering recently.

Comment: I read this title and was like "What?!  We have secret tags?!"  :P

Comment: @John I noticed it could be interpreted that way after I wrote it, then left it that way intentionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: *burninating the peasants* **BURNINATING THE COUNTRYSIDE**

Comment: -1 for COMIC SAAAAAANS!!